# Keras- Loss per sample within batch

Tags: keras

How do I get the sample loss while training instead of the total loss? The loss history is available which gives the total batch loss but it doesn't provide the loss for individual samples.

If possible I would like to have something like this:

```
on_batch_end(batch, logs, **sample_losses**)
```

Is something like this available and if not can you provide some hints how to change the code to support this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to get this information via callbacks since the loss is already computed once the callbacks are called (have a look at `keras/engine/training.py`). To simply inspect the losses you may override the loss function, e.g.:

```
def myloss(ytrue, ypred):
    x = keras.objectives.mean_squared_error(ytrue, ypred)
    return theano.printing.Print('loss for each sample')(x)

model.compile(loss=myloss)
```

Comment: Thanks Nemo...u r genius....it worked like a charm.....training.py can be updated to get these values via callback

Comment: Please consider accepting answers (click the check mark) if they helped solve your problem. This marks the question as answered in the overview and grants the person who answered additional points to the upvotes you give. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can be done using a callback. This is now included in the keras documentation on callbacks. Define your own callback like this

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

And then pass in this callback to your model. You should get per batch losses appended to the history ojbect.

Comment: I am looking for per sample loss in batch and not batch loss.

Answer (score 0):

I have also not found any existing functions in the Keras API that can return individual sample losses, while still computing on a minibatch. It seems you have to hack keras, or maybe access the tensorflow graph directly.

Answer (score 0):

set batch size to 1 and use callbacks in model.evaluate OR manually calculate the loss between prediction (model.predict) and ground truth.