# Inspect loss function **per sample** in evaluation, keras with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

In Keras/Tensorflow, I am trying to implement an active learning mechanism, for which I need to get a loss per sample. I currently execute `evaluate` over each sample and it takes so much time (one sample per 100 ms). Is there a good way to implement this?

I saw a similar thread, [Keras- Loss per sample within batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910579/keras-loss-per-sample-within-batch), but I do not understand the logistics there as it is just printing.

Is there anybody who has solved this with Keras/Tensorflow?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It looks like I can do it for `fit` using `Callback` and making the batch size 1, but I would like to do it for `evaluate` or `predict`.